# OR behaviour in python:

Tags: python

I have written the following piece of code, all i want to do is print a yes for if the number passed is a string representation of 1, 0 or 2 and for everything else a false:

```
number=raw_input()
if number is "1" or "0" or "2":
    print "Yes"
else:
     print "no"
```

I know how to make the intended logic work, but i just want <strike>need</strike> to know why it prints yes for any number i pass to raw_input. I'd like the answer to be as detailed as possible, because i cant understand why it would fail, it seems pythonic enough to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code, to Python, reads like this:

```
if (number is "1") or "0" or "2":
```

And as any non-empty string evaluates to `True`, it's always `True`.

To do what you want to do, a nice syntax is:

```
if number in {"1", "0", "2"}:
```

Note my use of a set here - while it doesn't matter too much in this case (with only three values) checking against a set is faster than a list, as a membership test for a set is O(1) instead of O(n).

This is simply a nicer and easier of writing this:

```
if number == "1" or number == "0" or number == "2":
```

Which is what you wanted.

Note when making a comparison for value you should always use `==` not `is` - `is` is an identity check (the two values are the same object). Generally you should use `is` for stuff like `is True` or `is None`.

If you wanted to handle this as a number, you could do something like this:

```
try:
   value = int(number)
except ValueError:
   value = None
if value is not None and 0 <= value <= 2:
    ...
```

Which could be more useful in situations where you want to compare to a large range of numbers. Note my use of Python's useful comparison chaining (`0 <= value <= 2` rather than `0 <= value and value <= 2`).

Comment: +1 for set literal (available in Python 2.7+), as well as warning against string comparison using `is`.

Comment: Thanks...especially for the note at the end, i did not know that.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
if number == "1" or number == "0" or number == "2":
    print "Yes"
```

Or the more Pythonic:

```
if number in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    print "Yes"
```

Or you can cast to `int` and try:

```
if int(number) in range(1,4):
    print "Yes"
```

The reason your code evaluates to `True` is all the time is because it is evaluating the truth of the `"0"` and `"2"`, which as statements are true in Python.

Comment: Note that using a list for this is a bad idea - while in this case with a small set of checks it doesn't really matter, checking for membership in a list is slower, so it makes sense to use sets. It's also worth noting your last example will throw exceptions if the input could potentially be something which isn't a number.

Comment: I was aware of the potential for the exception, but not of the performance hit for checking list membership. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Because every expression between an `or` is evaluated as a boolean expression.

`if True` evaluates to True, `if 1:` evaluates to True, `if "0":` evaluates to True.

So what you wrote is more or less the equivalent to:

```
if number is "1":
    print "Yes"
elif "0":
    print "Yes"
elif "2":
    print "Yes"
else:
     print "no"
```

You should have written `if number is "1" or number is "0" or number "2":` or, more pythonic: `if number in ("1", "0", "2"):`