# Python - Properly Use OR function

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OR behaviour in python:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460963/or-behaviour-in-python)

Probably extremely basic, but I'm a bit stuck after searching around. To me, this line of code should result in it printing "ELSE" as the string does not contain either word. Obviously it's not that simple and can't seem to figure out why. I've made sure to split the string in to a list just to make things easier to search. What am I doing wrong?

```
string = "Johnny Was Here Yesterday"
string = string.split()

if "Bob" or "Hello" in string:
    print "IF"
else:
    print "ELSE"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way is to do this:

```
if 'Bob' in text or 'Hello' in text:
    print 'IF'
else:
    print 'ELSE'
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because Python evaluates that as:

```
if ('Bob') or ('Hello' in text):
```

Because `'Bob'` always evaluates to `True`, your function always prints `'IF'`

By the way, it's not good to use `str` or `string` as a variable name, as it overwrites the *very useful* builtin method `str()` or the library `string`.

Comment: Please don't use `str`.  It's a very useful builtin function `str()`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee I thought it was `string()` - I really need to wake up... but now I can't think of why `string` is bad, or even **if** it's bad

Comment: It's bad - its the name of a standard library - http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: @DanielB of course - I'll edit that in

Answer (score 4):

In Python, non-empty string evaluate to True.

Your `if` statement is interpreted as follows:

```
if ("Bob") or ("Hello" in string"):
```

Since `"Bob"` is a non empty string, the statement always evaluates to `True`.

You should use something like

```
if "Bob" in string or "Hello" in string:
```

or

```
if any(map(lambda x: x in string, ["Bob", "Hello"]))
```

As noted in other answers, you may wish to reconsider using the variable name `string` as it clashes with one of pythons [standard libraries](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Answer (score 1):

The way it's written, there will be two tests; the first test is `if "Bob"`, the second test is `"Hello" in string`. `if str` is always true for any non-empty string, so `if "Bob"` always evaluates to true.

You can fix this by either using `if ("Bob" in string) or ("Hello" in string):`, or by using `if any((x in string for x in ["Hello", "Bob"]):`.

Answer (score 0):

"Bob" is a 3-length string, it is `True` when it is in the cause.

```
>>> bool("Bob")
True
>>> bool("")
False
```

You should modify to:

```
if "Bob" in string or "Hello" in string:
    print "IF"
else:
    print "ELSE"
```