# My code in python is not working

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OR behaviour in python:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460963/or-behaviour-in-python)

I'm a beginner to programming and chose python as my first language..

```
print "start the conversation"
conversation = raw_input()

if conversation == "Hi" or "hi" or "Hello" or "hello":
    print "Hey there!"

elif conversation == "How are you?" or "how are you?":
    print "I'm good and you?"
else:
    print "No one starts a conversation like this."
```

but when ever i run program it works fine well i type "Hi" it replies back "Hey there!" but whenever I type the following as input "How are you?" it still prints out "Hey there!" i want it to print out "I'm good and you?" instead of "Hey there!" again. Please make it easy as i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
if conversation == "Hi" or "hi" or "Hello" or "hello":
```

should read

```
if conversation in ("Hi", "hi", "Hello", "hello"):
```

Similarly for the `elif`.

The code that you have right now is syntactically valid, but doesn't do what you think it does (it basically always evaluates to `True`).

Comment: So how to i correct it?\

Comment: @user1977722: The way I've explained it in the answer.

Comment: Tuple is a bad choice here(`O(n)` lookup), use sets instead.(`O(1)` lookup)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Don't be silly. The cost of lookup is irrelevant here.

Comment: Yes for OP's example it's irrelevant, but for a bigger set of data it can matter a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is always True.
You should use:

```
if conversation == "Hi" or conversation == "hi" or conversation == "Hello" or conversation == "hello":
```

or

```
if conversation in ("Hi", "hi", "Hello", "hello"):
```

Comment: Tuple is a bad choice here(`O(n)` lookup), use sets instead.(`O(1)` lookup)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Don't be ridiculous. There are four options. Using `set` only confuses. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Particularly as creating the set from the tuple will be O(n) anyway, so you don't gain anything for a single lookup.